# date convert from yyyy-mm-dd to yyy-mm-dd converting year to day

Tags: mysql, sqldatetime

I have migrated data from old DB to new DB where date was taken as `varchar`, I have migrated data successfully but problem in date . In old DB the format of date is `25-01-02` where `25` is day `01` is month and `02` is year. But my script converted it to `2025-01-02`. How can I fix it in my SQL?

```
TEST case:
DATE                  OUTPUT
2025-05-01            2001-05-25
2002-08-16            2016-08-02
2031-01-01            2001-01-31
2028-08-16            2016-08-28
2001-05-01            2001-05-01
```

Comment: You need to use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: I have already tried can you modify it!

SELECT f_date  , 
CAST( DATE_FORMAT(f_date, '%y-%m-%d') AS CHAR),
DATE_FORMAT(CAST( DATE_FORMAT(f_date, '%y-%m-%d') AS CHAR),'%Y-%m-%d')
FROM table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can it easy convert with **STR_TO_DATE** like this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('25-01-02', '%d-%m-%y');
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('25-01-02', '%d-%m-%y');
+-------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('25-01-02', '%d-%m-%y') |
+-------------------------------------+
| 2002-01-25                          |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

See the Manual: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/str_to_date/

Comment: @Martin - I have add the link, but you can search by google with 2 words : **mysql str-to_date** to find anything

Comment: Yes Google is always an answer, but when the OP reads the answer and wants to know more about the function specified/recommended, it's good to have a link in the answer, else if the OP googles and gets something else that may not be what you intend.

Comment: I would suggest linking to the *MYSQL* manual as [`Although MariaDB is supposed to be compatible with MySQL, for one reason or the other there are quite a few compatibility issues and different features`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120178/whats-the-difference-between-mariadb-and-mysql)

Comment: @Martin - **YES** there is a difference: MariaDB is the better MySQL and **NO** there is no difference in the functions. MariaDB is a binary replacement from MySQL